# Asmack 18 connection : google.com:5222 Exception: Could not connect to talk.google.com remote-server-timeout

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, google-talk

I am trying to use asmack 18 to connect to gtlak server for XMPP connection.

```
public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
      //Connect to the server
      connection.connect();
      connection.login("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "password");
    // Set the status to available
      Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
      connection.sendPacket(presence);
      //xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
      Log.d("connection","connection successfull");
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
      connection = null;
      Log.d("connection","connection fail");
      //Unable to connect to server
    }
```

But it gives timeout error.
talk.google.com:5222 Exception: Could not connect to talk.google.com:5222.; : remote-server-timeout(504)
  -- caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: talk.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Read the ReadME =) http://asmack.freakempire.de/0.8.9/README

> ### Static Code
>
> In order to work correctly on Android, you need to register Smack's
>   XMPP Providers and Extensions manually and init some static code
>   blocks before you doing any XMPP activty. Calling
>   **SmackAndroid.init(Context)** (in org.jivesoftware.smack) will do this
>   for you.

```
    SmackAndroid.init(getApplicationContext());
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
...
```

.